# How to send an email using sendmail command?

Tags: command, sendmail

I installed sendmail on CentOS but did not configure it and started it as daemon. Can I send an email using the sendmail command like,

```
sendmail admin@remotedomain.com < ./myemailcontent
```

I have no luck with this command. It seems to connect to 127.0.0.1 then times out.

I think sendmail will connect to the remote smtp server(remotedomain.com) to deliver the email but it seems to use local smtp server to relay the email. How can I use sendmail to send an email?

Answer (score 3):

`sendmail` is "low level" tool/command to send email. It expects "raw" email.
Consider using higer level tools e.g. `mail`.

If you want to send simple email messages and prefer portability then take a look at the script below:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
# sendmail or "sendmail look alike" provided by postfix/exim/...
SENDMAIL=/usr/sbin/sendmail
## Or use custom "sendmail look alike" 
## e.g. msmtp which can send without local SMTP server
#SENDMAIL=/usr/bin/msmtp

TO=me@example.net

$SENDMAIL -i -- $TO <<END_OF_EMAIL
Subject: My test message subject
To: $TO
X-Comment: Use empty line to separate email headers from email body

My test message body
END_OF_EMAIL
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I ran your script but the email was not sent successfully. In fact, the email is queued in /var/spool/clientmqueue/. I know if I start the sendmail service(sendmail as daemon), the email will be delivered.  But I do not want to start the sendmail service on my machine. I just want to use the sendmail command to send an email. Is it possible?

Comment: Do you want send messages to a) local mailboxes b) remote servers? b => do you have permanent internet connection?

Comment: I want to send email to remote servers and I have permanent internet connection. I don't know the exact mechanism of the sendmail command and the sendmail service. I think for remote recipient sendmail command will talk with remote server to send the email, rather than deliver the email to local smtp server.

Comment: Even when I send email to local user like: sendmail -v root < ./mail, it seems to deliver to the local smtp server: "root... Connecting to [127.0.0.1] via relay...
root... Deferred: Connection refused by [127.0.0.1]
"

Comment: Make you script use configurable sendmail patch and use custom "sendmail look alike" e.g. msmtp to send external messages without any help from local smtp server.

Comment: So, it is the designed behavior that sendmail command will deliver all emails to local smtp server? What is "configurable sendmail patch "?

Comment: 1) Root user or mail group privileges may be required to deliver email to another local user/account mailbox.  Do you haveprocmai linstalled as set root id? `ls -l /usr/bin/procmail` -> `-rwsr-sr-x 1 root mail ...` 2) configurable sendmail path - I have modified my answer

Comment: I added "s" to /usr/bin/procmail just now, but the problem persists. sendmail always "Connecting to [127.0.0.1] via relay". Since I have not set up the sendmail service, the configuration file /etc/mail/sendmail.mc keeps untouched. Do I need to change something in this file so make the sendmail command work?

Comment: Or, I just give up because sendmail command is designed to deliver all emails to local smtp server and I have to start the sendmail service before I can use the command to send emails?

Comment: "sendmail by sendmail.org" requires running local sendmail daemon listening on 127.0.0.1:25.  It has been introduced to end long string of security problems created by earlier installation as set root uid.  Other SMTP/MTA (e.g. exim) have different requirements.

Comment: Thank you,AnFi! Do you know which version of sendmail does not need the local daemon running? I use the php mail function which calls sendmail. If I want the mail function to work, I have to set up a local smtp server, which is not convenient. I remember there is a sendmail version that has an -s option to specify an external smtp server. This is a little more convenient. The best solution I want is a sendmail version that does not need to specify a smtp server at all.

Answer (score 3):

To use **sendmail** you first need to install postfix:

`>> sudo apt-get install postfix`

youll have to configure the postfix settings by running `>> dpkg-reconfigure postfix` and following the instructions according to you. Then run `>> service postfix reload` to run the service.

**Note:** `/usr/sbin/sendmail` is aliased by using `sendmail` command. You can actually figure this out by typing `which sendmail`. So instead of typing in the file name you can just type in sendmail :)

---

To use `sendmail`:

*Example*:

```
>> sendmail recipient@whatever.com
Subject: Subject Line
... Email Body Here ...
```

Then press `CTRL+D` on a new line, this will send the email

if you find that your emails are slow or dont work properly this link has good intructions on what to do: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/sendmail-is-slow-to-send-mail

---

If you want to add a **File Attachment** with `sendmail` I recommend `uuencode`. To use it you need to install:

```
>> sudo apt install sharutils
```

`uuencode` encodes a file into email friendly text (https://linux.die.net/man/1/uuencode)

*Example*:

`uuencode /path/to/file.txt /path/to/file.txt | sendmail "recipient@whatever.com"`

Just remember that you have to put the `/path/to/file.txt` twice since it takes an input file and an output or else it will run a command line entry below.

Answer (score 0):

You need a working smtp service running like Postfix or `ssmtp`.

If it is all running, I find, the `sendmail` command syntax is not so intuitive, maybe you can use this function to use it:

```
send_email() {
    local recipient_email="$1"
    local subject="$2"
    local body="$3"

    if [ -z "$recipient_email" ] || [ -z "$subject" ] || [ -z "$body" ]; then
        echo "Usage: send_email <recipient_email> <subject> <body>"
        return 1
    fi
    echo -e "Subject: $subject\n\n$body" | sendmail "$recipient_email"
}
```

example:

```
send_email "your@email.com" "Test Subject" "Hello, this is the body of the email."
```